# Using Ratchet push.js in single page mobile app

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, single-page-application, ratchet, push.js

I'm developing a cordova based mobile app using `Backbone` and `Ratchet`. The app is based on single based architecture where the page are created and changed dynamically. From my knowledge, `push.js` works well with pages loaded from server through AJAX. How can I use `push.js` to transit from one page to another in single page architecture?